# Removing version history in Google Doc or Sheet without duplicating file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

Is it possible to remove the version history in Google Doc or Google sheet without duplicating the file. App Script solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/delete) to remove one or more revisions of a file. However, this method can only work with files that have binary content, not native Google formats.